# Chrome App: Handle Sensitive data

Tags: security, local-storage, google-chrome-app

I want to write a Chrome app that uses the GitLab API (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/tree/master/doc/api). In order to use the API a user needs her/his private token. The token is returned after a successful login via API '/session'.

Is there a secure way for Chrome Apps to store sensitive data like the private token from GitLab? Can I use the chrome.storage for this or will the token be stored in clear text to the users computer?

Comment: chrome.storage will store it in clear text.

Comment: Even if it were "secure" (in quotes because it's not), the key to the encryption would also be stored on the user's computer. If the key weren't available, your app wouldn't be able to use the data. If users want real security, they should use whole-disk encryption with a strong passphrase, and take advantage of OS-level account security.

Comment: I agree with @sowbug. Most likely you'll have to implement this on a server-side component, and proxy your requests through that.

Comment: I discuss another alternative below.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the [WebCrypto API](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/) to implement encryption of the token, then store the ciphertext in chrome.storage. You'll ask the user to supply a master password to encrypt and decrypt tokens. On each launch of the app you'll prompt the user for the master password, to avoid the need to store it anywhere.

In all likelihood, you'll grow tired of entering the master password each time and will implement an option to store the password right next to the stuff it unlocks in chrome.storage, or you'll pick a password that's short and easy to type. In either case, the usability of the system will ensure that the password serves effectively no purpose, other than security theater.